# Adding a order to master inventory using excel macros

Tags: excel, vba

I have two separate excel workbooks. One is an order form, the other is a master inventory file.

I have a column where I input the order amount for each individual items (let's say it spans from cell C2:C130, each row is a different item). My optimal solution is to develop a macro that takes that order and adds it to an existing master inventory to keep track of total orders.

I wrote some code that I thought would work:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Variant
Dim lDestLastRow As Variant
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\Designs Work\Master_Inventory.xlsm"
Set wsCopy = Workbooks("Production file_Dave Edits").Worksheets("Order")
Set wsDest = Workbooks("Master_Inventory").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Range("E2:E130")
Set lDestLastRow = wsDest.Range("E2:E130")
lDestLastRow.Value = lDestLastRow.Value + lCopyLastRow.Value
End Sub
```

when I run this code, I get a mismatch error (type 13?).

So I went into the watch window to see the type of each expression and the combined right side of the equation is a "variant/integer" type, whereas each individual expression is a "variant/variant" type. Moreover, when I run the code and call only one cell instead of a matrix, the code works; it doesn't run when multiple cells are called.

Can anyone help? Or have a more elegant code? Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to do with the lcopy last row and ldest last row?  you're setting them as ranges, then adding the value of two ranges, rather than somethign where you would sum up the values in two ranges and then add that value.

Comment: Which line does the error occur on?

Comment: @Cyril my money is on the `+` operation involving two variant arrays

Comment: The error occurs on the last line of code. The entire right side of the equation creates a mismatch error. I would assume @MathieuGuindon is correct. The "+" is creating the error. I'm not vba savvy enough to understand how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

```
Set lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Range("E2:E130")
Set lDestLastRow = wsDest.Range("E2:E130")
```

This makes both variables `Variant/Range`, because the `Set` keyword says the right-hand side of the assignment operator is yielding an object reference: the two variables might as well be declared `As Range`.

Now, the `Value` of a `Range` object that refers to multiple cells, is a 2D `Variant` array.

```
lDestLastRow.Value = lDestLastRow.Value + lCopyLastRow.Value
```

That's where you're getting the *type mismatch* error, because you can't use the `+` operator with array operands.

> *when I run the code and call only one cell instead of a matrix, the code works*

That's because a single-cell `Range.Value` returns that numeric value, and `+` will work with that - although, if the cell contains an error value (e.g. `#REF!` or `#VALUE!`), you'll *still* get a *type mismatch* error, because a `Variant/Error` can't be an operand.

I wish I could help beyond that, but I have no idea what this `+` intends to be doing.

As for a more elegant solution, I'd recommend indenting the procedure body, moving declarations closer to their assignment, and keeping a reference to the destination "inventory" workbook:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = Workbooks("Production file_Dave Edits").Worksheets("Order")

    Dim inventoryBook As Workbook
    Set inventoryBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\Designs Work\Master_Inventory.xlsm")

    Dim destSheet As Worksheet
    Set destSheet = inventoryBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.Range("E2:E130")

    Dim destRange As Range    
    Set destRange = destSheet.Range("E2:E130")

    'todo: figure out intent
    'lDestLastRow.Value = lDestLastRow.Value + lCopyLastRow.Value

End Sub
```

If that `+` intends to add everything up in both ranges, you could use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(sourceRange) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(destRange)`, although I doubt that's really want you're looking for.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the quick response! Ultimately, the intent is to have the order form workbook populate the order into a inventory workbook that has the total orders over time. So I used the "+" to add the new order to the already existing inventory. Does that make sense?

Comment: You're missing logic to get "the new order" and the "already existing inventory" then; that's not something anyone that can't see your data can help with though.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more? I'm a bit confused :(

Comment: You're saying you're trying to add "the new order" to "the already existing inventory", but that's not what you have. "the new order" would be *one* of the values, not the entire range; same for "the already existing inventory", it's *one* of the values - and without knowing what your data looks like, there's no way anyone can help you figure that out. Maybe your source has an `ID` or an `ItemNumber` associated to a `Qty` - in which case you need to lookup the `Qty` for a given `ItemNumber` in the source, then locate the corresponding cell in the destination, add the two values...

Comment: ...*for each individual cell* in the `destRange`

Comment: Thank you, I think I can wrap my head around that. The order form does have an ID for each item and an associated quantity for that item. But I have no idea how to create the code necessary for the lookup (I'm just trying to help a friend out; I don't have real VBA experience).

Comment: You could do that without any VBA though - just have a temporary "AdditionalQty" column in your destination sheet, then use `=IFNA(VLOOKUP(...),0)` to lookup the quantities from your source sheet, copy/pastespecial/values/add onto the original quantities, then delete the temp column ;-)

Comment: That could work? Is there anyway we can message directly? I've never used this site before

Comment: Well SO is a Q&A site (see the [tour]), not exactly a live troubleshooting platform, but once you get 20 reputation points you will be able to talk in [chat].

Comment: That's what I figured. However, I'm not close to the required points to start a chat. You wouldn't happen to know of another platform that could be used? If not, no worries. I'll get it sorted